# How to build dynamic dilv layout from list use jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try to build custom layoutd on page. I want to build somethinh like this:

[image]

I try few method to do this but i didn't find solution.

I try to use such method but for me it's not working:

```
var areaList = [
    { name: "area1", color: "#f3d33a", width: 540, height: 400 }
]

function createAreas() {
    $(areaList).each(function (i, data) {
        console.log(data.color)
        splitAreas(data.color, data.width, data.height)
        var objects = `
<div class="col-4">
<div class="areas">
</div>
</div>`

        $(".container").append(objects);
    });
}

function splitAreas(color, width, height) {
    console.log(color, width, height)
    $(".areas").css("background-color", "yellow")
    $(".areas").css("width", width + "px")
    $(".areas").css("height", height + "px")
}
```

Comment: Research [Masonry](https://masonry.desandro.com/)

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan i see this, but i need to build this layout from list

Comment: Not sure of the issue there. The source of the data isn't relevant.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan i just try to buld you example from list, and i have problems